# Page number (Word) of selection through VBA to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have an Excel file from where I generate and print a Word document.
To find the page number of a bookmark:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sg_Annexe_C_Tableaux").Select

MsgBox ActiveDocument.Selection.PageNumber ' => gives a 438 "object doesn't support _ 
                                           '                 this property or method"
MsgBox ActiveDocument.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument) ' => also 438 
MsgBox wdPageNumber                        ' => returns 7
MsgBox wdActiveEndPageNumber               ' => returns 3
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sg_Annexe_C_Tableaux").Range ' => returns the text to which
                                                       '    the bookmark points
```

I wonder, how I should do it, after having tried for 3 hours with all the various solutions posted on the net ... Like [this one on windowssecrets.com](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/16137-How-do-I-find-what-page-a-Bookmark-is-on-%28VBA-Word-2000%29) does not work.

What is the correct command to get the page number of a selection?

EDIT:

The only page number information that we can get is the total page count using this codes:

```
ActiveDocument.Content.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
ActiveDocument.Content.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
```

The guys from [thezcorp.com](http://www.thezcorp.com/VBACodeSamples.aspx) brought me on that track.

Background:
The number of this exact page is needed, since we generate a .pdf from this very .doc and some inserted .pdf pages that come in the middle. The position in the middle has a bookmark, from which the page number is kept and later used, when the .doc has been converted to .pdf. At that point the two files are combined over the `insertpages` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sg_Annexe_C_Tableaux").Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
```

or:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sg_Annexe_C_Tableaux").Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

See:

- [Range Object (Word)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff845882.aspx)
- [WdInformation Enumeration (Word)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837003.aspx)